# Running executable files in GUI

Tags: gui, executable, execute-command

I have an executable file called `drracket` in a folder :

[image]

However in GUI it appears as a source file :
[image]

Is there a way to run the file via GUI like double-click etc.? (Running it in prompt forces me to keep the prompt open 
and bound to the executing file, closing the prompt closes the program as well).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.desktop`.

1. You need to make the shellscript as executable.
2. put `.desktop` file in same path.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Name=App Names
   Comment=your Comments
   Exec=/bin/sh "path of script like /opt/mefile/file"
   Icon=/opt/softwares/icon.png
   Categories=Application;
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Terminal=0
   ```
3. Make the `.destop` file executable by +x.
4. now double click in .desktop file and it will launch your application.